# jQuery UI showing tabs as list

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui, tabs

I am using jQuery UI along with Wordpress to display tabbed forms. The jQuery seems to be adding the tabs markup correct.

```
<div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/community_users_form/profile_edit/<?php echo $cid.'/'.$userid?>">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Communities</a></li>
        <li><a href="/community_users_form/roles_edit/<?php echo $cid.'/'.$userid?>">Roles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Admin</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5">Delegation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-6">Payments</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-7">Email</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-8">Activity</a></li>
      </ul>
```

Changes to

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="ui-id-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true"><a href="/community_users_form/profile_edit/2568/" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">Profile</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3">Communities</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="ui-id-5" aria-labelledby="ui-id-4" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false"><a href="/community_users_form/roles_edit/2568/" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-4">Roles</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-4" aria-labelledby="ui-id-6" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#tabs-4" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-6">Admin</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-5" aria-labelledby="ui-id-7" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#tabs-5" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-7">Delegation</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-6" aria-labelledby="ui-id-8" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#tabs-6" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-8">Payments</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-7" aria-labelledby="ui-id-9" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#tabs-7" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-9">Email</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-8" aria-labelledby="ui-id-10" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#tabs-8" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-10">Activity</a></li>
      </ul>
```

The tabs appear as a normal list and not tabs.

[image: List view]

Comment: i think you missed js or css

Answer (score 1):

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/pygtkm0k/)

```
             <div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                      <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
                        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="ui-id-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true"><a href="/community_users_form/profile_edit/2568/" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">Profile</a></li>
                        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3">Communities</a></li>
                        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="ui-id-5" aria-labelledby="ui-id-4" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false"><a href="/community_users_form/roles_edit/2568/" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-4">Roles</a></li>
                        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-4" aria-labelledby="ui-id-6" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#tabs-4" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-6">Admin</a></li>
                        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-5" aria-labelledby="ui-id-7" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#tabs-5" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-7">Delegation</a></li>
                        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-6" aria-labelledby="ui-id-8" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#tabs-6" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-8">Payments</a></li>
                        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-7" aria-labelledby="ui-id-9" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#tabs-7" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-9">Email</a></li>
                        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-8" aria-labelledby="ui-id-10" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#tabs-8" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-10">Activity</a></li>
                      </ul>

                <script>
                      $(function() {
                        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
                      });
                </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. I was including jquery-ui.theme.css and not jquery-ui.css